# how i select from 2 database table and limit the content in 40?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i have 3 tables i want to select 2 table id out and limit the show up content

table name as chat

```
id | user_id | chat | date
 1     1         a     2016-05-29 12:02:58
```

table name as chatroom_chat

```
chatroom_id | chat_id |
 1               1
```

here is my php code with sql statement

```
     $chatroomID=$_GET['chatroomID'];
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM chatroom_chat WHERE chatroom_id ='$chatroomID'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $chat = $row['chat_id'];

     $sql3 ="SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT * FROM chat,chatroom_chat WHERE id = '$chat' AND chat_id= '$chat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,40
                ) sub
                ORDER BY id ASC LMIT 0,40";

    $getChatData = mysqli_query($connection,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $getUserID=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = '$chat'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    while($getUserIDRow=mysqli_fetch_array($getUserID)){
        $postUserID=($getUserIDRow['user_id']);
    }

    $getUsername=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$postUserID'");
    while($getUsernameRow=mysqli_fetch_array($getUsername)){
        $postUsername=($getUsernameRow['username']);
    }

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($getChatData)) {
        $color = ($row3['user_id'] == $userID) ? '#FFFFFF' : '#66FFFF';
        $position = ($row3['user_id'] == $userID ) ? 'right' : 'left';
        $border = ($row3['user_id'] == $userID) ? ' 1px solid black ' : ' none ';

        echo "<div class='msg-dateandtime' style='text-align:$position; float:$position;'> <div class='left-username' style='color:blue;'>" .$postUsername."</div>"
                . "<div class='space'></div>"
                . "<div class='right-date'>  ". $row3['date'] ." </div></div>"
                . "<div class='wrap-message' style='background-color:$color; border:$border; float:$position;'>"
                . "<p style 'text-align=$position; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:left;'> ".$row3['chat']."</p></div>";
    }

}
```

now there is no any error show up. Just the chat wont be limit show on 40.

Comment: What about if you add an additional `LIMIT 40` next to `ORDER BY id ASC`?

Comment: it will have error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LMIT 0,40' at line 4`

Comment: Make sure you use alias for every derived table. For eg 'chat.id' instead of 'id'. It will enhance the readability of the query too

Comment: Why are you asking duplicate questions of your own. You asked this like an hour or so ago? Welcome to Stackoverflow. Four questions on one day is not terrible. But you need to go to a PHP and Mysql tutorial site and learn stuff bro.

Comment: @Drew sorry bro i didn't check the question asking by my friends== because we are using the same account. i will check before i ask. Thank for your advice

Comment: Also, give some of your questions answers a Green check mark down in the answer area to reward the person that spent the time to solve it for your guys. Good luck.

Comment: @Drew thank you because i still new here.and thank for you comment let me know whats wrong i am doing.

Comment: You can take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), scroll down 1 page, and see the Green check mark. If someone solves your problem, then pick the best one in your judgment for that question and give it the Green thingie. It gives you points, and them. Also, find a mysql tutorial somewhere for a day.

Comment: That is just my opinion. No better than anyone else's

Comment: @Drew thank you i will do it when i free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to use the join query.

Also What I can guess from the code in while loop at first is that you are running some other mysql query on same table. 
Use the query as

```
   $sql3 ="SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM chat LEFT JOIN chatroom_chat ON chat.id = chatroom_chat.chat_id WHERE id = $chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 40
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC";
```

This will select the results fromthe tables with chat.id = chatroom_chat.chat_id

Post the complete code so that it can be further optimized.
Hope it helps.

@Chew.. Here you go with full code. Just validate the parameters and strings as required

```
$chatroomID=$_GET['chatroomID'];
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];

    //This will select all the chats from table chat with id corresponding to that of chat_id in chatroom_chat table
    $sql3 ="SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * FROM chat LEFT JOIN chatroom_chat ON chat.id = chatroom_chat.chat_id WHERE chatroom_id = $chatroomID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 40
        ) sub 
        ORDER BY id ASC";
    $getChatData = mysqli_query($connection,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $chatData = array();
    $user_ids = '';
    while($getRowChatData=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getChatData)){
        $chatData[]= $getRowChatData;
        $user_ids .= $getRowChatData['user_id']+',';
    }

    $users = array();
    $getUsername=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN ($user_ids);
    while($getUsernameRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsername)){
        $users[(string)$getUsernameRow['id']]    =    $getUsernameRow['username'];
    }

   for($i = 0; $i < count($chatData); $i++) {

        $color = ($chatData['user_id'] == $userID) ? '#FFFFFF' : '#66FFFF';
        $position = ($chatData['user_id'] == $userID ) ? 'right' : 'left';
        $border = ($chatData['user_id'] == $userID) ? ' 1px solid black ' : ' none ';

        echo "<div class='msg-dateandtime' style='text-align:$position; float:$position;'> <div class='left-username' style='color:blue;'>" .$users[$chatData['user_id']]."</div>"
                . "<div class='space'></div>"
                . "<div class='right-date'>  ". $chatData['date'] ." </div></div>"
                . "<div class='wrap-message' style='background-color:$color; border:$border; float:$position;'>"
                . "<p style 'text-align=$position; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:left;'> ".$chatData['chat']."</p></div>";
    }

}
```

Comment: tq very much i get the idea

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM chat INNER JOIN chatroom_chat ON
chat.id=chatroom_chat.chat_id WHERE chat.id='$chat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40;
```

You can write a shorter query using **inner join** as above. it is also, simple to understand. All you have  to specify is `LIMIT 40` in order to get 40 rows only.